# How to install compiler tools with opkg on MIPS CPU architecture

Tags: compiling, opkg

I just bought a set top box (digital reciever - [Vu+ Solo2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vu%2B)) which runs Linux, and would like to compile some C software on it. It uses OPKG as the package manager. I executed

```
opkg update
```

and:

```
root@vusolo2:~# opkg install gcc
Unknown package 'gcc'.
Collected errors:
opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package gcc.
root@vusolo2:~#
```

I figured that this is because I do not have the necessary repositories. The files in `/etc/opkg/` only point to `feeds/repositories` that are owned by the creators of the Linux image that the receiver is running ([Black Hole](http://www.vuplus-community.net/board/threads/black-hole-3-0-1c-vu-solo2-oe-3.26292/)).

As far as I understood, the repositories need to match the CPU architecture. Here is the output of `/proc/cpuinfo`:

```
root@vusolo2:~# cat /proc/cpuinfo
system type : BCM7346B2 STB platform
machine : Unknown
processor : 0
cpu model : Broadcom BMIPS5000 V1.1 FPU V0.1
BogoMIPS : 864.25 cpu MHz : 1305.007
wait instruction : yes
microsecond timers : yes
tlb_entries : 64
extra interrupt vector : yes
hardware watchpoint : no
isa : mips1 mips2 mips32r1
ASEs implemented :
shadow register sets : 1
kscratch registers : 0
core : 0
VCED exceptions : not available
VCEI exceptions : not available
processor : 1
cpu model : Broadcom BMIPS5000 V1.1 FPU V0.1
BogoMIPS : 655.36
cpu MHz : 1305.007
wait instruction : yes
microsecond timers : yes
tlb_entries : 64
extra interrupt vector : yes
hardware watchpoint : no
isa : mips1 mips2 mips32r1
ASEs implemented :
shadow register sets : 1
kscratch registers : 0
core : 0
VCED exceptions : not available
VCEI exceptions : not available
```

Now, which repositories should I use to get the following packages:

```
gcc
gcc-symlinks
make-dev
binutils-dev
libgcc-dev
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found myself in this position today and the answer seems to be – simply: You don't want to. Just cross compile.

The [Entware-ng opkg repository project](https://github.com/Entware-ng/Entware-ng/wiki) provides a nice toolchain for this purpose, with instructions [**here**](https://github.com/Entware-ng/Entware-ng/wiki/Compile-packages-from-sources). They only support [native compilation](https://github.com/Entware-ng/Entware-ng/wiki/Using-gcc-(native-compilation)) on ARM|x86* and conclusively state:

> There is no gcc for mipsel repo.

See also: https://github.com/Entware-ng/Entware-ng/issues/138